# Not able to connect to Elasticsearch in Docker

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, information-retrieval

I am not able to connect to elasticsearch in kubernetes inside docker. My elasticsearch is accessed via kubernetes and I have an index called 'radius_ml_posts'. I am using elasticsearch's python library to connect to elasticsearch. When I run the whole process on my python IDE (Spyder), it works just fine. However, when I try to run it inside a docker container, I get connection issues. What am I missing? Below are my configs and code:

The `localhost:9200`:

```
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-dev-client-6858c5f9dc-zbz8p",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "lJJbPJpJRaC1j7k5IGhj7g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "8453f77",
    "build_date" : "2019-03-21T15:32:29.844721Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My python code to connect to elasticsearch host:

```
def get_data_es(question):
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host": "elastic", "port": 9200}], connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, max_retries=30,
                       retry_on_timeout=True, request_timeout=30)
    #es = Elasticsearch(hosts='http://host.docker.internal:5000', connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, max_retries=30, timeout=30)
    doc = {'author': 'gunner','text': 'event', "timestamp": datetime.now()}    
    es.indices.refresh(index="radius_ml_posts")
    res = es.index(index="radius_ml_posts", id = 1, body = doc)
    res = es.search(index="radius_ml_posts", size = 30, body={ "query": {
                                                                "query_string": { 
                                                                "default_field": "search_text",
                                                                "query": question
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    )
    return res
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.7.0
    container_name: elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  myimage:
    image: myimage:myversion
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    expose:
      - 5000
    networks:
      - elastic


volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -U nltk
RUN python3 -m nltk.downloader all
RUN pip --default-timeout=100 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

The docker commands I am running stepwise:

1. `docker build -t myimage:myversion .`
2. `docker-compose up`

The error I am getting:

```
myimage_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
myimage_1            |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
myimage_1            |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
myimage_1            |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
myimage_1            |     raise value
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
myimage_1            |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
myimage_1            |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
myimage_1            |   File "main.py", line 41, in launch_app
myimage_1            |     ques = get_data_es(ques1)
myimage_1            |   File "/app/Text_Cleaning.py", line 32, in get_data_es
myimage_1            |     es.indices.refresh(index="radius_ml_posts")
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 92, in _wrapped
myimage_1            |     return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 42, in refresh
myimage_1            |     "POST", _make_path(index, "_refresh"), params=params, headers=headers
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 362, in perform_request
myimage_1            |     timeout=timeout,
myimage_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 157, in perform_request
myimage_1            |     raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
myimage_1            | elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='elastic', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /radius_ml_posts/_refresh (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f967a9b1710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))) caused by: ConnectionError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='elastic', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /radius_ml_posts/_refresh (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f967a9b1710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')))
```

Please help in fixing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand that you say you're running your Elasticsearch in Kubernetes, but you're attempting to write a docker-compose file. What is the purpose of using docker-compose here?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very handy with elasticsearch and docker. Can you propose a way to solve this? Another methodology maybe? I also tried without the docker-compose file and I got the same error.

Comment: If the Elasticsearch database is running in Kubernetes, typically you'd run any workloads that need it in Kubernetes too.  Use the DNS name of its Service as the host name to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using the host as:

```
host:"host.docker.internal"
```

Code change,

```
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host": "host.docker.internal", "port": 9200}], connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, max_retries=30,
                       retry_on_timeout=True, request_timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `ELASTICSEARCH_NODES` variable in your application environment section as and then consume the variable in your python code as `http://ELASTICSEARCH_NODES`:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.7.0
    container_name: elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  myimage:
    image: myimage:myversion
    depends_on:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_NODES=http://elastic:9200
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    expose:
      - 5000
    networks:
      - elastic


volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean I should change the python code as follows:

`es = Elasticsearch(hosts='http://ELASTICSEARCH_NODES', connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, max_retries=30,
                       retry_on_timeout=True, request_timeout=30)`